# Assigning jQuery buttons on the fly fails partly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a layout where a user is (going to be) able to select a template. Based on the button the user clicked, all matching (by class-name) buttons are evaluated and updated.

Let's say I have 4 buttons for four different templates. Each button, naturally, can be clicked. The clicked button should become the new activated template, the other buttons should be reset (because before another template was active). I thought I had this figured out but for some reason, when I want to re-assign a new button, only the last button is replaced with a new button. The other previous buttons are not.

The situation provided in the JSFiddle is not a full functional solution, but I'm curious why only the last button is handled correct. Can anyone tell me something more about this?

The fiddle can be found: http://jsfiddle.net/z3jYC/. (it's a working example, providing the bare code to show the example).

This is the code:

HTML:

```
<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="temp1">activate template</button><br/>
<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="temp2">activate template</button><br/>
<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="temp3">activate template</button><br/>
<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="temp4">activate template</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    $('button').button();
    var oButton = $('<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="">activate template</button>').button();

    $('.activate-tpl').click(function() { 

        var sClicked = $(this).attr('data-template-name');

        $('.activate-tpl').each(function() { 

            if($(this).attr('data-template-name') != sClicked) { 

                var oNewButton = oButton;
                oNewButton.attr('data-template-name', $(this).attr('data-template-name'));
                $(this).replaceWith(oNewButton);
            } else { 

                $(this).replaceWith('You\'ve activated me!');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question. What is the expected behaviour when a button is clicked? It should be replaced with a text, right? And the other buttons should be "reset". What do you mean by that?

Comment: The button clicked should be replaced with text, the other three buttons should be replaced with three new buttons. The strange thing is that only the last button is replaced. When I try the same to replace all items with text it works as expected. (`$(this).replaceWith('some text');`)

Comment: Okay I see. Then my answer might help you. ;)

Comment: @Ben -- Think I got it working how you want, let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's you're new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z3jYC/2/

A few things I noticed:

--I changed your `.attr("data-template-name");` to `.data("template-name");`
--The loop wasn't re-scanning your changed template because you were removing the class `activate-tpl` from it! I added spans with this class.
--I changed your click event to use `.on` due to the dynamically replaced content

```
if(data.data("template-name") != sClicked || !data.is("button")) { 
    var oButton = $('<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="' + $(this).data("template-name") + '">activate template</button>').button();

    $(this).replaceWith(oButton);
} else { 
    $(this).replaceWith('<span class="activate-tpl">You\'ve activated me!</span>');
}
```

I also changed how you assigned the button, seemed to work out a little nicer.

Edit: I noticed if there is no `template-name` data, the replacement button gets assigned a blank value. If this continues, multiple buttons are assigned this value, resulting in multiple buttons being replaced.

Changed your appending text to:

```
data.replaceWith('<span class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="' + sClicked + '">You\'ve activated me!</span>');
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. This is really helpfull (as well as the answer provided by Fredrike S). From here on I can start working on the real work ;) +1 and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

When I click a button in the jsfiddle you provided I see the text "You've activated me" right where I clicked. All other buttons except one disappear. The remaining button does not have any functionality when I click it.

So some things that might help you:

**Q: Why is there only one button visible after the click?**

**A**: You create the `oButton`outside the `$.each` loop. So there is only one button that can be placed somewhere in your HTML. It is NOT duplicated. Thus when you go through the loop the last button that has `$(this).replaceWith(oNewButton);` will be created. Any other call before that has no effect.

To avoid this you need to create a new button every time.

```
 var oNewButton = $('<button class="activate-tpl" data-template-name="">activate template</button>').button();
```

**Q: Why do the new buttons not react to a click?**

**A**: The new buttons are really new objects and have nothing to do with the old button. So the click-event handler `$('.activate-tpl').click(..)` does *NOT* have any effect because the new buttons are created *after* the click-handler was registered.

To solve this problem I'd recommend to keep the old buttons and just change whatever you want to change. When they are clicked and the template should be shown you could just hide them using `.hide()`.

Hope that helps. ;)

**Edit**: Here's an example of what I think you wanted: http://jsfiddle.net/pWwgm/

Comment: Thanks for your reaction! +1. I figured that if I made a button outside `.each` I would have a defined button instance which I could use multiple times (by assigning `oButton` to `oNewButton`). Greetings from Holland to Germany after a promising football week ;)